# Postgres locking issue

Tags: postgresql, locking, subquery

I have the following Postgres table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_db.url_data (
    url varchar(2500) NOT NULL,
    status int,
    priority int,
    ...
    last_update_ts timestamp,
    CONSTRAINT url_data_pk PRIMARY KEY (url)
);

CREATE INDEX i1_url_data ON my_db.url_data(priority, status);
```

I have a separate process that several times a day will add url's to the table.  The table is being used as a FIFO queue.  I have a process that needs to get the next url based on priority (lowest priority is better).  When records are added to the table, status is NULL.  Once I have processed the records, the status is updated to an integer.
I have 3 nodes running the application that processes the records.  Each node is running 16 threads all reading from the table (queue)

I use the following sql to get the next url:

select url, priority
from my_db.url_data
where status is null and priority=
(select min(priority) from my_db.url_data
where status is null) for update skip locked limit 1;

This appeared to work beautifully for the first 2.5 million records that all had priority 5000.  Beyond the first 2.5 million records are 1 more record for priority 5000 and another 3 million records with priority 5500 and 13mm more records at lower priority (higher #).

The issue I am having is that when there is only 1 record left for priority 5000, the sql does not return any record and appears blocked.

I need the ability to set the order of processing based on priority.  Restarting each node didn't help.  I confirmed there were no outstanding locks before restarting to no avail.  It wouldn't process the single record of priority 5000.  I was able to coerce it to resume processing by updating the priority on that single record to 5500.

I can have higher priority (lower #) records added at various times, so those should take precedence over lower priority (higher #) records when they are added, therefore I can't use ordering as an option because each select has to be very quick (e.g. sub ms) which I am able to achieve thus far.

Why would the sql I have block when there is only 1 record for the currently processing priority group?

Comment: How did you confirm there were no outstanding locks?  This looks just like what would happen with one outstanding lock, and unlike everything else I can think of.

Comment: I executed a query I found to show locks and it was blank.  To get it started all I did was update the priority of the 1 5000 priority record to 5500 (update was successful) and all the threads were able to pick up messages with priority 5500